# SDF and MDF, two database in one application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to use two databases in one application, i.e. SQL Server database and Local Database (`.sdf` = SQL Server Compact Edition)?

So some user can use it on network, but for another users is that not important.

Can I create two project, one for SQL Server for example (I have  already LINQ to SQL). And another for Local Database where `.sdf` file is added with DataSet and so on. And than I planned to compile my solution including one of this two project, depends on my customer's needs (SQL Server or Local Database). I have also Business Layer and GUI which stay the same. Can this be done or there is some other way how to do this?

I am using Visual Studio 2012

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compact is not fully compatible with "real" SQL Server. Check the LocalDB instead: supports everything that express edition does, but simplified setup and doesn't run as a windows service.

Comment: Thanks, I just added LocalDB in VS2012 and all what i have to do is change app.config so my app connect to right database. The databases just needs to have the same schema and tables. Thank you.